# Test if Django ModelForm has instance on customized model

Tags: python, django

related question: [Test if Django ModelForm has instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704067/test-if-django-modelform-has-instance)

<del>According to the question&answer above, we can check if a modelform has instance as `hasattr(form.instance, 'pk')`, because `instance` must have `pk`.</del>

I misunderstood the related question. it says

> Try checking if `form.instance.pk` is `None`.

---

<del>But</del> in my case where the model's primary key is customized as:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    myid = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

And the modelform:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

<del>has `pk` attribute on instance, after `is_valid()`:</del>

```
data = {'myid': '123'}
form = MyModelForm(data=data, instance=None)
form.is_valid()
if form.instance.pk is not None:
    print('detect: modelform received an instance')
else:
    print('detect: modelform didnt receive an instance')
```

My question is:
In this case, how to check if a modelform was set with an existing instance?
Or, **how to check if the mode of modelform is "edit on existed entry" / "new entry to our DB"?**

Comment: `pk` is just a proxy name for your private key `myid`. It represents the same field in db.

Comment: You didn't read the linked answer properly. It specifically says *not* to use hasattr, as it will always return True.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ah... yes you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your model has a primary key column, than `pk` property of that model will always be there and be an alias to that field.

In your case you do not want to check if your `form.instance` has a property named `pk` (that's the `hasattr` line). Instead you have to check if the property `pk` of `form.instance` is empty or not:

```
data = {'myid': '123'}
form = MyModelForm(data=data, instance=None)
form.is_valid()
if form.instance.pk: 
     print('This has a pk! It was saved before!')
else:
     print('This has no pk! It was never saved!')
```

If it is a new model, not yet saved, than the `form.instance.pk` field's value will be `u''` (empty string), which evaluates to `False` in if statement, which does what you what it to.