# Python typehints and linters

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, lint, type-hinting

I've been adding static typechecking to our python project, for example like this:

```
from typing import List
from something import MyOtherClass

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.some_var = None  # type: List[MyOtherClass]
```

However, now the linters we use (flake8 and pylint) report for example `List` as unused variables, since they are not used in actual code. (pep8 handles it fine, by the way).

So we end up changing the code to this:

```
from typing import List  # noqa # pylint: disable=unused-import
from something import MyOtherClass  # noqa # pylint: disable=unused-import

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.some_var = None  # type: List[MyOtherClass]
```

Is there any better solution to solve this? We don't want to disable all unused import warnings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 3.6 implements [PEP 526: Syntax for Variable Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), which as the name suggests introduces new syntax for variable annotations, removing the need for type comments.

In the new syntax, your code would be rewritten as:

```
from typing import List, Optional
from something import MyOtherClass

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.some_var: Optional[List[MyOtherClass]] = None
```

... or alternatively:

```
from typing import List, Optional
from something import MyOtherClass

class MyClass:

    some_var: Optional[List[MyOtherClass]]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.some_var = None
```

Since `List` and `MyOtherClass` now appear as actual tokens in the code, rather than comments, linters should have no trouble acknowledging that they are indeed being used.

Comment: I am new to type checking, so sorry if it is a stupid question, but is it really necessary to define that `__init__()` (the constructor) returns `None` ?

Comment: @Guillaume according to [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-meaning-of-annotations), *"the return type of `__init__` ought to be annotated with `-> None` . The reason for this is subtle. If `__init__` assumed a return annotation of `-> None` , would that mean that an argument-less, un-annotated `__init__` method should still be type-checked? Rather than leaving this ambiguous or introducing an exception to the exception, we simply say that `__init__` ought to have a return annotation"*

Comment: Ah great, looking forward to the 3.6 release then!

Answer (score 4):

[@Zero Piraeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1014938/zero-piraeus) answer offers the most recent solution to this (i.e use variable annotations, also see: [What are variable annotations in Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations-in-python-3-6)).

Apart from that, you don't even *need* to import `List` when you're using `# type:` comments. `mypy` doesn't require them to be imported and neither to `pyflakes` or `pylint` as far as I am aware.

There's no need to import names from `typing` unless you require to use their name somewhere that Python actually performs a name look-up (and in comments, this isn't required.)

Comment: I just tried it, and mypy does not require imports of the typing module members, but it requires imports of any other classes/types not in the typing module

Comment: @tobspr yep it does. If you only use `type:` comments you don't need to import stuff from `typing`. Everything else is of course required as an import. if you define a function that takes a list as `def foo(a: List[int])` you'll need to import `List` from `typing` in order for the name to be resolved.