# mypy trouble with inheritance of objects in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

Python 3.6.5 and mypy 0.600

I wrote the code:

```
from typing import List


class Animal():
    pass


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super()

    def bark(self) -> None:
        pass


class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super()

    def meow(self) -> None:
        pass


arr1: List[Dog] = [Dog(), Dog()]
arr2: List[Animal] = [Dog(), Dog()]

# error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[Dog]", variable has type "List[Animal]")
arr3: List[Animal] = arr1
```

I don't understand, why I have an error 'Incompatible types in assignment ' with a variable 'arr3'. 
Dog is a class which inherits from a Animal. 
For example, I don't have an error with variable 'arr2'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Imagine that this would be possible:

```
arr3: List[Animal] = arr1
```

Now you think you have list of animals, but this is actually a list of dogs (note that `arr3` is not a copy of `arr1`, they are *the same* list).

And because you think this is the list of animals you can add a `Cat` to it.

However, because this is actually list of dogs, you cannot add a `Cat` to it. Otherwise you will fail on `AttributeError` after trying to use dog-specific attribute.

More generally, list is invariant - `List[Animal]` cannot be assigned to `List[Dog]` (because it can already contain cats) and `List[Dog]` cannot be assigned to `List[Animal]` (because you can add cat later)

---

This might not be obvious in Python, but you can make simple test:

```
arr3: List[Animal] = arr1 
arr3.append(Cat())
for dog in arr1:
    print(dog.bark())
```

Mypy does not allow this because this assignment might break your code logic

Comment: What's wrong with adding cat to `List[Animal]`? This was an issue with mypy that is now resolved in Python-3.7

Comment: There is nothing wrong with adding cat to `List[Animal]`. There is problem when you are adding cat to `List[Dog]`. And because `arr1` is still list of dogs, it wont become list of animals after assigning to variable with type of `List[Animal]`

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how this can be related to the types? what OP is trying to do is to add `List[Dog]` to `List[Animal]` it's a sensible hierarchy. Specially when they're dog inherits from animal.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted earlier: this answer is absolutely correct. For OP: if you'd like more details, mypy's docs has a [section on invariance vs covariance](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#invariance-vs-covariance).

Comment: Animal -> Dog is a hierarchy, but `List[Animal]` -> `List[Dog]` is not.

Comment: @Kasramvd: note that OP's code isn't adding `List[Dog]` to `List[Animal]`: it's replacing the list outright.

Comment: @Michael0x2a Yep, now I see what's happening here. However the problem here is that it's replacing the list outright instead of reassigning the elements. And this is not a correct behavior when you're using typing. That's why they resolve it in Python-3.7.

Comment: @Kasramvd: I'm not really sure what you're referring to -- I pay pretty close attention to changes in mypy and the typing ecosystem as a whole and to my knowledge the semantics of lists, invariance, and covariance haven't been changed during at least the past 2 years. Doing `animals = dogs` has always been illegal; doing `animals.extend(dogs)` has always worked.

Comment: @Michael0x2a Well `arr3: List[Animal] = arr1` works fine in Python-3.7 and returns `[<__main__.Dog at 0x7f8e9b05fd68>, <__main__.Dog at 0x7f8e9b05fbe0>]` as expected.

Comment: @Kasramvd: That's because types are ignored at runtime. This has nothing to do with Python 3.7: all versions of Python 3 (starting from 3.0) will run OP's code (assuming the `typing` module backport is installed when necessary). However, type checking tools like mypy will reject OP's code regardless of what version of Python he or she is trying to run. For more details see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41356784/646543).

Comment: @Michael0x2a ah yes, you're right. It seems that I've mixed the behavior of Mypy with the built-in typing module. Seems kinda obscure now. It's too much abstractions quilted together here.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using `Sequence[Animal]`, [which is covariant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence).

`List[T]` is invariant; it will only handle items of exactly type `T`. This means `List[Dog]` is **not** a subtype of `List[Animal]`. This is because of what @awesoon mentioned, which is that it prevents you from accidentally adding items which are incompatible with T:

```py
# this won't compile:

dogs : List[Dog] = [dog1, dog2]
animals : List[Animal] = dogs # compiler error: List is invariant

# if the compiler allowed the previous line,
# then `dogs` would be [dog1, dog2, cat] after the next line
animals.push(cat1)
```

On the other hand, `Sequence[T]` is covariant with T, which means that a `Sequence[Dogs]` **is** a subtype of `Sequence[Animals]`. This is allowed because a `Sequence` does not have "insert" methods, so you can never accidentally sneak a `Cat` in a `Sequence[Dog]`:

```py
dogs : List[Dog] = [dog1, dog2]
animals: Sequence[Animals] = dogs # this is fair game for the compiler
animals.push(cat1) # compiler error: Sequence has no method push
# since Sequences can't add new items, you can't
# accidentally put a cat inside a list of dogs =)
```

Comment: Great solution! It saved me hours of potentially pointless thinking :)