# Python typing is not getting enforced

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

I'm testing the typing features of ^Python3.6 however it seems like it's not doing anything, I can do this without getting an error:

```
my_var: int = 0
my_var = 'str'
# no error

def ret_var(my_var: int) -> int:
    return my_var
ret_var(my_var)
# also no error
```

how can I get this throw an exception or at least a warning ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use type hints in python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356784/how-to-use-type-hints-in-python-3-6)

Comment: @Georgy I'm not sure, there's an answerable question at the end not in the linked question, specifically how to use annotations in a way that throws an exception.

Comment: @Andy I can see that in the duplicate target OP has the same request though: "_I would like the following effects: If it's obvious that I used the wrong type just as shown above, throw out a warning or error_"

Comment: @Georgy you're right, looks like my brain skipped over that line when I was reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type annotations don't do anything in and of themselves to enforce types, what they do is prepare your code to be evaluated by a typechecker such as Mypy, along with allowing programmatic reading of function annotations for things like more intelligent decorators.

If you want to start enforcing types without using a type checker for some reason, you can decorate your functions. I have one such decorator available on [github](https://github.com/osoleve/type-enforcer) that supports `Union[]`, `Optional[]`, and `Any` in addition to standard annotations:

Usage:

```py
from type_enforcer import enforce_types


@enforce_types
def foo(x: int, y: float) -> int:
    return int(x * y)
```

```py
>>> try:
>>>     foo(5, 2.0)
>>> except TypeError as e:
>>>     print(str(e))
10

>>> try:
>>>     foo(5, 2)
>>> except TypeError as e:
>>>     print(str(e))
Argument y supplied wrong type: expected float, got int.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this answers all my questions, I just don't get why the python team designed it to behave like that.

Comment: the URL is broken