# Scalar type checking does not work in python

Tags: python, typing, strict

Scalar type checking does not work in Python (v 3.8.6).

```
def test(x: int) -> int:
    print(type(x))
    return x

a = test('a')
```

It doesn't matter at all that there is no int as an input parameter. It also does not indicate that int is not an output parameter.

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
```

I would expect ValueError!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328920/is-python-strongly-typed

Comment: Python is dynamiclly typed, typing is only HINT not rules

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356784/how-to-use-type-hints-in-python-3-6

Comment: That is not how Python type hinting works. Doing `x: int` does not *require* `x` to be an `int`.  What does is provide a hint to an IDE that can warn you if the way you are calling the function disagrees with the type hint. If you only feel comfortable programming in a strongly-typed language then maybe Python is not for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is **Function Annotations**.

`def test(x: int) -> int`.

This means that the function is expected to take and `int` argument and is also expected to have an `int` return value. These are optional and are not enforced by Python but they are useful to static type analysis tools, and aid IDEs with code completion and refactoring.

Read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-function-annotation