# Python type hinting with numbers

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I've just come across a strange behaviour with Python's type hinting.

```
>>> def x(y: int):
    return y
>>> d=x('1')
>>> print(type(d))
<class 'str'>
>>> d
'1'
```

When I pass a number as string into the function where the argument is cast as int, it still produces string. I think a key to this unexpected behaviour is that it is not casting, but hinting. But why does it behave like this? If I pass 'one' as an argument it gives me a NameError.

Comment: Python is not a compiled language, and the type hinting system is not used at runtime (unless you are using some specific third-party libraries). These typehints allow you to run static analysis tools such as mypy to determine if your code is respecting the contacts of functions/methods and respecting variable types when doing assignments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use type hints in python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356784/how-to-use-type-hints-in-python-3-6)

Answer (score 5):

You're not casting anything inside the function and type hints are just that; hints. They act as documentation, they don't cast or coerce types into other types.

To do so you need

```py
def x(y):
    return int(y)
```

And now to accurately type hint this function

```py
def x(y: str) -> int:
    return int(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's type-hinting is purely for static analysis: *no* type-checking at runtime is done at all.  This will also work:

```py
x("One")
```

Your `One` failed because `One` does not exist, but this will work:

```py
One = "seventeen"
x(One)
```