# How to force static typing in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.6, typing, static-typing

Since static typing is available in Python 3.6, is it possible to force static typing for a Python project or set of Python files?

Comment: Static typing is **not** available in python yet. Type hints or type annotations are for static analyzers like mypy which is not the same as static typing.

Comment: @Drako The TypeError is from normal Python operation. i.e., if you removed the hints, it would still raise an error. (`'this is ' + <int>` raises it). `def f(s: str) -> str: return 0` and then calling `f(0)` does not raise  a TypeError for me (Python 3.6.1)

Comment: Relevant if not dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5/32558710#32558710 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations-in-python-3-6?noredirect=1&lq=1?

Comment: @Drako: there is no type-checking at runtime as per PEP484: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Comment: Have you considered using type_enforced to force your static typing hints? See: https://github.com/connor-makowski/type_enforced

Comment: use mypy to enforce it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`annotations`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) in Python3, which might help you get some benefits of static typing.

**However if static typing were to be completely enforced in Python, then it won't be Python anymore.** It's a duck-typed dynamic language, and would loose all dynamism as a result. If you really intend to use a statically-typed language, you are better off not using Python.

Comment: I like its dynamicness, but Python's been evolving as well. When a project grows beyond a certain threshold, type checking begins to matter a lot, exponentially. I think there's a good chance the language eventually would allow optional type enforcement.

Comment: @j4hangir that's where well written tests come into picture and you can get the best of both worlds. Static typing or not, automated tests are indispensable anyway.

Comment: I'd opt for optional enforcement, similar to mypy. Personally I find myself type hinting nearly 80% of all my code, as the payoff is always great using a good IDE.

Comment: @j4hangir but then you will start expecting others to do the same as well. That's where it starts going south.

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm certainly against making it mandatory too but it would be pretty nice to have builtin tools to say, check the type of parameters `when` they're optionally annotated. We don't need `int` for the `i`, but passing wrong parameters, wrongly ordered, etc. has been a src of headache for me.

Comment: I'm not denying the benefits of static typing. I'm saying it has both pros and cons. And there are tools available like kite and anaconda that will provide somewhat of the IDE functionality you want. It won't be as effective of course

Comment: use mypy to enforce it

Comment: > and would loose all dynamism as a result.
This doesn't seem correct, TypeScript is a dynamic language; even when static typing is fully enforced there's plenty of dynamism. Even Swift has dynamic capabilities built in with robust type checking.

Comment: @Awesome-o depends on how you define dynamic language. For me, it has to work with duck-typing (i.e. as long as objects provide certain behaviour, their types shouldn't matter) without littering the code with interfaces everywhere or generic "ANY" types :)

Answer (score 16):

I think you cannot force static typing but you can use a checker as `mypy`.

According to line 2 of *The Zen of Python* by Tim Peters, you have "Explicit is better than implicit." Static typing is a good thing, but "Simple is better than complex." ...

```
$ python3.6
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Comment: Static is (usually) better than Dynamic typing!  It is not about efficiency, it is about readability.  E.g. is "User" the name, the number, the system structure, the database row, or something else?

The big idea Java got from Lisp and gave to C# is that there is no need for a dichotomy between scripting languages and efficient languages.  It is possible to have both.  C# in particular can produce efficient code that is also easy to work with.

Comment: static typing is explicit, more readable and reduces ambiguity.   python should have a mode to enforce it (mypy style is fine).    eventually it can use this enforcement at load-time to produce optimized bytecode

Comment: Why not use something like [type_enforced](https://github.com/connor-makowski/type_enforced) for on the fly type checking?