# What is this odd colon behavior doing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6.1, and I have come across something very strange. I had a simple dictionary assignment typo that took me a long time to find.

```
context = {}
context["a"]: 2
print(context)
```

Output

```
{}
```

What is the code `context["a"]: 2` doing? It doesn't raise a `SyntaxError` when it should IMO. At first I thought it was creating a slice. However, typing `repr(context["a"]: 2)` raises a `SyntaxError`. I also typed `context["a"]: 2` in the console and the console didn't print anything. I thought maybe it returned `None`, but I'm not so sure.

I've also thought it could be a single line if statement, but that shouldn't be the right syntax either.

Additionally, `context["a"]` should raise a `KeyError`.

I am perplexed. What is going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are variable annotations in Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations-in-python-3-6)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You have accidentally written a syntactically correct *variable annotation*. That feature was introduced in Python 3.6 (see [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/)).

Although a variable annotation is parsed as part of an [annotated assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#annotated-assignment-statements), the assignment statement is *optional*:

```
annotated_assignment_stmt ::=  augtarget ":" expression ["=" expression]
```

Thus, in `context["a"]: 2`

- `context["a"]` is the annotation target
- `2` is the annotation itself
- `context["a"]` is left uninitialised

The PEP states that *"the target of the annotation can be any valid single assignment target, at least syntactically (it is up to the type checker what to do with this)"*, which means that the key doesn't need to exist to be annotated (hence no `KeyError`). Here's an example from the original PEP:

```
d = {}
d['a']: int = 0  # Annotates d['a'] with int.
d['b']: int      # Annotates d['b'] with int.
```

Normally, the annotation expression *should* evaluate to a Python type --
 after all the main use of annotations is type hinting, but it is not enforced. The annotation can be any *valid* Python expression, regardless of the type or value of the result.

As you can see, at this time type hints are very permissive and rarely useful, unless you have a static type checker such as [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/).

Comment: Shouldn't this require an `=` assignment operator then? The key doesn't exist. This just feels wrong to me.

Comment: In this case, `:` *is* the assignment operator. We're just "assigning" a type annotation alone, not a key. I doubt there's any reason for allowing it, just an unintended side affect of adding the annotation syntax.

Comment: @chepner It seems this is no side-effect imho. This is exactly what the corresponding PEP was designed to do.

Comment: It's weird that it'll allow you to annotate a target that hasn't yet been defined though.  If my very first line is `x: str` and immediately followed by `type(x)`, the interpreter will raise a `NameError`.  IMO the syntax should enforce the object is pre-defined, or is defined on the spot.  This just introduces confusion.

Comment: @Idlehands This defeats the purpose though. Having `x = 'i am a string'` prior to `x: str` makes the latter kind of redundant.. This shouldn't have been added at all. It was fine as comment; I never show it used one way or the other.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis When you are converting a dictionary definition to an assignment `d = {"a": 2}` to `d["a"] = 2` it can cause a very nasty typo that is hard to find. Especially in django when the dictionary is a context and you only use that key in a template. In that case it never raises an error and everything just works in a very wrong way.

Comment: @HashSplat Sounds like a strong candidate for testing. This would break your code no more than `d["a"] = {2}` would, which is IMO an equally easy-to-make typo.

Comment: @Idlehands Having `x: str` wouldn't affect `type`, a class called on _the value of `x`_.

Comment: @Idlehands Allowing this syntax probably enables you to use type hinting in function definitions. In `def f(x: str): ...`, `x` is also not defined at the moment of being annotated.

Comment: Does this mean that, since `2` is an `int`, that element is hinted to be an integer?

Comment: @HashSplat This doesn't do anything (may have little impact on run time in case of NameError etc.). Its purpose is to be a hint for static analysis, nothing more. It's clearly explained in the linked PEP.

Comment: @justengel I made the same mistake today and took me a while to figure out the exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

The annotations are automatically stored in `__annotations__` which is a dict.  For `x: y`.  `y` must be a valid expression, i.e. `y`, or whatever is on the right side of the `:`, has to evaluate.  On the other hand `x` ,must, at a minimum be able to be a key, thus hashable.

In addition, the LHS cannot be a set, because sets are unhashable,
`>>> {2}: 8`

`SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation`

nor a list:
`>>> [2]: 8`

`[2]: 8 SyntaxError: only single target (not list) can be annotated`

nor a tuple:

`>>> (2,3): 8`
    `(2,3): 8 SyntaxError: only single target (not tuple) can be annotated`