# name error not defined in python

Tags: python, string, nameerror

So this is the basic string (the text is in hungarian before you are wondering):

```
>>> nev=input("add meg a neved: ")
add meg a neved: Kristóf
>>> print("Üdvözöllek, " + nev)
Üdvözöllek, Kristóf
>>> print("egy út előtt állsz")
egy út előtt állsz
>>> print("elindulsz rajta")
elindulsz rajta
>>> arany: 0
>>> print("Most" + str(arany)+ "aranyad van")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    print("Most" + str(arany)+ "aranyad van")
NameError: name 'arany' is not defined
```

The error message claims that the name is not defined, even though I gave it a value in the IDE,  and I just cannot figure out what exactly did i wrote wrong...

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How did arany: 0 work? it should be arany = 0

Answer (score 2):

It should be `arany = 0`, not `arany: 0` - I'm not sure why that's even valid.

Comment: [It's 100% valid Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48323493/what-is-this-odd-python-colon-behavior-doing)

Comment: Yep, seems like this was introduced in Python 3.6.