# Python exercise about lists

Tags: python, list

Take the list

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

Write a program that prints out all the elements of the list that are less than 5.

- Instead of printing the elements one by one, make a new list that has all the elements less than 5 from this list in it and print out
  this new list.
- Ask the user for a number and return a list that contains only elements from the original list a that are smaller than that number
  given by the user.

I solved as that:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

num = int (input( "Choose a number: "))

new_list: []

for i in a:
  if i < num:
    new_list.append(i)
print (new_list)
```

but doesn't work, any advice? Thank you

Comment: `new_list: []` -> `new_list = []` or simply `new_list = [n for n in a if n<num]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this odd Python colon behavior doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48323493/what-is-this-odd-python-colon-behavior-doing)

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for creating a variable with an empty list is wrong.

You want

```
new_list = []
```

rather than

```
new_list: []
```

---

Also in Python, the standard is not to have space between keywords and brackets. `print('hello')` instead of `print ('hello')`.

Comment: Rookie mistake, thank you so much