# why interpreter is not throwing error if I add colon after print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I add colon and semicolon after print but interpreter is not throwing error.

please run with python3.8.x(edit)

```
x=5
print:(x)
print;(x)
```

Comment: `print;(x)` is a function, that is not called, follow by a parenthesized expression.

Comment: Because it is not actually an error.  What kind of error were you expecting?

Comment: For semicolon: [Why is semicolon allowed in this python snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48323493/7851470)

Answer (score 5):

The interpreter thinks the colon is a type annotation. Which is why it raises `SyntaxError` in earlier versions of Python, but is [valid syntax in Python 3.6+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-526-syntax-for-variable-annotations).

In later versions of Python this is valid

```
a: int
```

As is this

```
import sys

def exclaim(string):
    sys.stdout.write(f"{string}!")

print = exclaim
print("Hello")
```

I.e. You can annotate the type of a variable. And you can reassign `print`.

So when you do `print:(x)` the interpreter just thinks you're annotating `print` to be of "type" `5`.

Semi-colons are valid Python, and are used to put two separate statements on the same line. They're just considered to by "unpythonic". You do see them used sometimes to do things like `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: But why? According to [PEP526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#specification) it should look like `my_var: int`. Why it still considers it to be valid?

Comment: In 3.5, it works in a function definition, but not by itself; maybe a bug in 3.5

Comment: @Pat-Laugh I get the same result in 3.7.5.

Comment: Not exactly:  `print:(int)` would annotate with int.  `print:(x)` annotates it with "5".

Comment: @wim Yes, good point. Edited.

Comment: @RatnapalShende Type annotations don't actually affect the type. Or even restrict the values that can be assigned to it. They're really only used by type checkers like `Mypy`.

Comment: Got it bro....... Thank you so much for your breef explainantion !

Comment: @Batman *"the interpreter just thinks you're annotating print to be of "type" 5"* Well, this is still wrong I guess. `5` is not a `type` but `int` is.  `>>> type(int)
<class 'type'>  >>> type(5)
<class 'int'>`

Answer (score 2):

for `print;(x)`, the interpreter treats it like 2 different statements, `print` and `(x)`. The interpreter prints out "<built-in function print>" and "5". The print function is a built-in function. x is set to 5 so it prints out 5 too.
`print:(x)` is a type annotation as said in @Batman's answer

Comment: Can you explain how is it a valid type annotation? `print` may be the `my_var` in `my_var: int` but how `(x)` represents a type? It's an expression...

Comment: print;(x) is not printing anything in python3.8 as you mentioned above...

Comment: @RatnapalShende I said it prints it out in the interpreter.

Comment: got it ! Thank you bro for your valuable time!

Comment: @aidan0626 why print;(x) doesn't prints anything if we run it from file?

Comment: @RatnapalShende, it is because "print" returns "<built-in function print>" and "x" returns 5. The interpreter is made to print the value of any statement you give it. If you run it from file, that doesn't happen.

Comment: Understood bro hurray....! Thank you so much....!