# Django - Mail is not sent. Port changes to 25 but in seetings.py is set to 587

Tags: python, django, django-email

Email is not sent. What is interesting... before (like 3 mos ago) entire code worked perfectly fine.

**Settings:**

```
DEBUG = True

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT: 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xyz@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xyz'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

**view.py:**

```
def index(request):
    """The home page."""

    # Send a message.
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form_email = EmailForm()
        form_message = EmailMessageForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; proecess data.
        form_email = EmailForm(data=request.POST)
        form_message = EmailMessageForm(data=request.POST)
        if form_email.is_valid() and form_message.is_valid():
            try:
                email = Email.objects.get(text=request.POST['text'])
            except:
                form_email.save()
                email = Email.objects.last()
            
            message_db = form_message.save(commit=False)
            message_db.email = email
            message_db.save()

            message_owner = (
                f'New email on your website from {request.POST["text"]}',
                f"Email has been sent from: {request.POST['text']}\n\n"
                f"Full message:\n\"{request.POST['message']}\"",
                'settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER',
                ['my@gmail.com',],
            )

            message_guest = ('Your email has been sent',
                "Many thanks for getting in contact with me. Your message was "
                "successfully sent. I will reach out to you as soon as possible."
                f"\n\nYour message:\n\"{request.POST['message']}\"",
                'settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER',
                [request.POST['text'],],
            )

            send_mass_mail((message_owner, message_guest), fail_silently=False)

            return redirect('home:contact_thank_you')

    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'form_email': form_email, 'form_message': form_message}
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

**Traceback:**
Request Method: POST

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 4.1.5

Exception Type: TimeoutError

Exception Value: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connectio n failed because connected host has failed to respond

Raised during:  home.views.index

[image]

**I found the reason but I can't find any solution to fixe it!** This is what I've got when email has been sent:

[image]

The port is set to `587` in `seetings.py` (as shown above), but somehow this value is `25` instead of `587` after sending the email.

In [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-EMAIL_PORT) you can see that `25` is the default value, but why is it not overridden by my settings?

Comment: Surely `'settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER'` should not be in quotes (twice).  You want the value of the variable here, not just a string that contains the variable name.

Comment: _3 mos ago entire code worked perfectly fine_ Did you make any changes to the code since then?

Comment: nope, I didnt change anything. Even when I issue 'git checkout .' in order to revert all changes, the result is the same. I'm curious whats going on :D

Comment: `EMAIL_PORT: 587` must be `EMAIL_PORT = 587`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48323493/what-is-this-odd-colon-behavior-doing

Comment: @IvanStarostin omg I spent a lot of time to find the reason and I couldn't notice this... yeap if you replace equal mark to colon it works...

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you don't want quotes around the email addresses.  Also note that, unlike with a tuple, you do not need a trailing comma to create a one-item list:

```
            message_owner = (
                f'New email on your website from {request.POST["text"]}',
                f"Email has been sent from: {request.POST['text']}\n\n"
                f"Full message:\n\"{request.POST['message']}\"",
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                ['my@gmail.com'],
            )

            message_guest = ('Your email has been sent',
                "Many thanks for getting in contact with me. Your message was "
                "successfully sent. I will reach out to you as soon as possible."
                f"\n\nYour message:\n\"{request.POST['message']}\"",
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                [request.POST['text']],
            )
```

Comment: how can I get access to the settings variable in the view.py file?

Comment: Have you done `import settings`?

Comment: do you mean? `from django.conf import settings`. It looks that I dont have access to `EMAIL_HOST_USER`, I dont see this variable on the displayed list when `settings.` is provided (screenshot attached at the end of the main entry)

Comment: I found the reason and it is not related to this variable. Somehow port changes to 25... I modified main entry.

Answer (score -1):

I found not the best solution but it works...

If you have the same issue, go to:

\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py

then open this file and replace `port` to `587`:
[image]
[image]

But it is not the best practice I hope somebody find better solution how to fix it.