# Why Python acepts colon in a wrong variable declaration

Tags: python, syntax

Python syntax accepts sentces like this:

```py
var:{'a':'b', 'b':'c'}
var2:0
```

¿Why?
In those sentences there is no variable declaration neither function declaration o conditional statment.
After execute that lines if you require to use var you will find an error:
NameError: name 'var' is not defined.

why is not marked as a syntax error? or how is that colon proccesed by python?

Comment: perhaps a clearer explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48323493/what-is-this-odd-colon-behavior-doing (fwiw I think this should be a `SyntaxError`)

Comment: Variable annotations don't require an assignment, and can consist of an arbitrary expression.