# What is this new Python syntax called?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am dealing with some installation scripts from Github and am trying to execute [this script](https://developer.blender.org/source/pillar/browse/master/pillar/__init__.py) which looks like it fails because of these lines:

```
current_app: 'PillarServer' = LocalProxy(_get_current_app)
"""the current app, annotated as PillarServer"""
```

Executing it with Python 3.5 returns this error:

```
$python main.py
  File "main.py", line 33
    current_app: 'PillarServer' = LocalProxy(_get_current_app)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help me a bit here? I am not an expert in Python but am forced to use this script.

Comment: That error is very descriptive.  That is invalid syntax.  Just look at how to declare variables in python to see that.

Comment: literally is just invalid variable assignment. what it says on the tin here bud.

Comment: maybe it's meant to be something like `current_app = LocalProxy(_get_current_app())` since `_get_current_app` is a function? who knows

Comment: Which version, exactly, are you using? Variable annotations, defined by [PEP-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), weren't added until Python 3.6.

Comment: I am using 3.5. On Debian Stretch this is the highest it goes...

Comment: The annotation looks somewhat gratuitous; you *might* be able to simply get rid of it if you have to use this code. `current_app = LocalProxy(...)`. (Annotations are supposed to be used only by static analyzers, not the script itself, but I haven't looked at the code closely.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations-in-python-3-6

Comment: @chepner Thank you for expanding my knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [PEP-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/)-style variable annotation. You appear to be running the code with an older version of Python; you need to use Python 3.6 or later to recognize that syntax.

Comment: Good call. Didn't even know type hint existed heh.

Comment: Thank you! Oh god I have to try this asap so I don't get too many negative votes...

Comment: It's something you could have quickly googled for maybe. Or realised that that's not how you assign variables in python 2.x :^)

Comment: @L_Church It's a little hypocritical to claim the OP could have quickly googled the answer when your own comment suggests you didn't do likewise.

Comment: shhhh thats for us to know only