# __slots__ type annotations for Python / PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

How can I provide type annotations for attributes which are defined via `__slots__`? E.g. for this class:

```
class DiffMatch:
  __slots__ = ["ref_seq_idx", "ref_txt", "hyp_txt", "start_time", "end_time"]

  def __repr__(self):
    return "%s(%s)" % (self.__class__.__name__, ", ".join(["%s=%r" % (a, getattr(self, a)) for a in self.__slots__]))
```

(Python 2 compatible in a comment if possible (otherwise Python 3 only is fine), and also such that PyCharm can handle it (actually that is most important for me now).)

Comment: Note that without any default values for those attributes, the `__repr__` method will throw an `AttributeError` on `getattr(self, a)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__slots__` only tells the `type()` object to make space for **potential** attributes. The names in the list are *not themselves attributes*. All you have is a bunch of descriptors. There are no values, so no types.

So you need to make actual attributes, and those have all the regular options for type annotations.

For Python 3.6 and up, use [variable type annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations-in-python-3-6):

```
class DiffMatch:
    __slots__ = ["ref_seq_idx", "ref_txt", "hyp_txt", "start_time", "end_time"]

    ref_seq_idx: int
    # ...
```

or for versions before 3.6 (including Python 2), you have to annotate the types on a method that can set the attributes. There is no real instance attribute support otherwise. You can add a dummy method for this:

```
class DiffMatch:
    __slots__ = ["ref_seq_idx", "ref_txt", "hyp_txt", "start_time", "end_time"]

    def __type_hints__(self, ref_seq_idx, ...):
        """Dummy method to annotate the instance attribute types
        # type: (int, ...) -> None
        """
        self.ref_seq_idx = ref_seq_idx
        # ...
```

where all the types for each of the arguments are listed in the docstring. If you have a `__init__` method for your class that also touches all the attributes, then a dummy method is not needed.

Note that you can't set class default values for these, which means that you can't use `ref_seq_idx = None  # type: int` (pre-Python 3.6) or `ref_seq_idx: int = None` (Python 3.6 and up); `__slots__` names are converted to descriptor objects on the class, so the names are already set.

Last but not least, I would take a serious look at the [`attrs` library](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) to build these types for you. Support for this library has [recently been added to PyCharm 2018.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#v2018-2-python), so type information is automatically picked up:

```
@attr.s(slots=True)
class DiffMatch:
    ref_seq_idx = attr.ib(init=False)  # type: int
    # ...
```

and you'll get your `__repr__` method generated for free. The `init=False` annotation tells `attrs` not to include that name in the `__init__`, at which point instances won't have that attribute set at all on instantiation.

Comment: Yes I know what `__slots__` does. With type annotations, I mostly meant just specifying a docstring which is recognized by PyCharm. But what you are saying is basically that I should just add sth like this in the class? `ref_seq_idx = None  # type: int` *Edit* I just tried, but then it complains that this conflicts with class variable in `__slots__`. *Edit* Ok, doing the same thing in `__init__` works.

Comment: @Albert: yes, on Python versions without variable type annotations you can't set class defaults for slots, because those would clash with the descriptor objects with the same names that `__slots__` create.

Answer (score 2):

The `attrs` library mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52553217) looks pretty neat. Though, I believe the folowing code would be a way to achieve what you want without it:

```py
class DiffMatch:
    ref_seq_idx: int
    ref_txt: str
    hyp_txt: str
    start_time: Decimal
    end_time: Decimal

    # __annotations__ is a dict and we can
    # construct __slots__ from its keys.
    __slots__ = tuple(__annotations__)
```

Comment: That link does not lead to a related answer?

Comment: @JustinFuruness Copy-paste error. Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My solution now:

```
class DiffMatch:
  __slots__ = ["ref_seq_idx", "ref_txt", "hyp_txt", "start_time", "end_time"]

  def __init__(self):
    self.ref_seq_idx = None  # type: int
    self.ref_txt = None  # type: str
    self.hyp_txt = None  # type: str
    self.start_time = None  # type: Decimal
    self.end_time = None  # type: Decimal

  def __repr__(self):
    return "%s(%s)" % (self.__class__.__name__, ", ".join(["%s=%r" % (a, getattr(self, a)) for a in self.__slots__]))
```

Comment: Your empty `__init__` argument list and `repr()` output clash now. You can't recreate your `DiffMatch()` instance by passing in values, so your `repr()` should not pretend that it can.

Comment: And on a separate note: you probably want to use a [`attrs` dataclass](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) for this; I added an example and further motivation to my answer.