Are there any drawbacks to assigning `__slots__` from `__annotations__` in a Python class?
With Python's type annotations, classes that declare __slots__ often end up duplicating the class identifiers.
A brief example:
class Event:
    location: tuple[float, float]
    index: int

    __slots__ = (
        "location",
        "index",
    )

An alternative to this is to use annotations to declare slots.
class Event:
    location: tuple[float, float]
    index: int

    __slots__ = tuple(__annotations__)

Is there any reasons to avoid deriving __slots__ from __annotations__ in Python 3.10 & newer?

Notes:

This was suggested as an answer to this question:
__slots__ type annotations for Python / PyCharm by @mike-r.

A similar question here:
Is it a good practice to use __annotations__.keys() for __slots__? 
...which I wasn't aware of when asking this.



FWIW, maybe what you really want is a dataclass: @dataclass(slots=True)

This is assuming there are no members declared anywhere besides the class body, right? (e.g. you could have declarations on self in __init__.)

This might break in Python 3.14. There are some major changes coming to how __annotations__ works, and I haven't been able to find documentation on how __annotations__ will work during class body execution. Most of the focus is on how it will work on fully-built class, module, and function objects.

@wjandrea yes, although it shouldn't be possible to declare class instance members outside of __slots__ in the __init__ function.

Is the use of __annotations__ in a class statement like this even documented? I'm not sure I would do this at all. In https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html, I see mentions of an object's __annotation__ attribute, and a module-level __annotations__ member, but this seems to be using the eventual Event.__annotation__ but as a name that shadows the module __annotation__.

@chepner this came from an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553143 which seemed neat but suspicious - hence the question here (edited the original question, including a link).

Three issues that I can tell make usage like this rather broken:

This doesn't support forward-declarations of attributes, so __slots__ must go at the end:
class A:
    __slots__ = tuple(__annotations__)
    a: int

>>> A.__slots__
()


Incorrect detection involving ClassVar:
from typing import ClassVar

class A:
    a: ClassVar[int]

    __slots__ = tuple(__annotations__)

>>> A.__slots__
('a',)


Type-checkers (at least, mypy) don't understand it (see mypy Playground):
class A:
    a: int
    __slots__ = ('a',)

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.asdf: str = ""  # Error

class A_auto_slotted:
    a: int
    __slots__ = tuple(__annotations__)

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.asdf: str = ""  # No error



There's also something obscure that happens if you annotate __slots__ and assign __annotations__ directly (note that __slots__ is supposed to be able to be a dict), although this is less likely to happen in real code:
class A:
    __slots__: dict[str, object] = __annotations__

ValueError: '__slots__' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable

