# Incompatible types in assignment when creating a dict out of two lists

Tags: python, mypy

When joining two lists into a dict, `mypy` complains about incompatible types in the assignment. Like this:

```py
from typing import Dict
d = Dict[str, int]

ln = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lc = [3, 5, 7]
d = dict(zip(ln, lc))
print(ln)
print(lc)
print(d)
```

The output shows that it's working alright:

```
% python3 blurb.py
['a', 'b', 'c']
[3, 5, 7]
{'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 7}
```

But `mypy` shows:

```
% mypy blurb.py
blurb.py:6: error: Cannot assign multiple types to name "d" without an explicit "Type[...]" annotation
blurb.py:6: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[str, int]", variable has type "Type[Dict[Any, Any]]")
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Why is that? Specificylly the second error looks confusing.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the lists. See a minimal reproducible example: [mypy playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=8b40e6f1eb35c053a9a9f34a5bbe1d62). The problem is that you accidentally wrote `d = Dict[str, int]` instead of `d: Dict[str, int]`, so instead of [annotating the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39971929/7851470) `d` with the type of `Dict[str, int]` you actually created a [type alias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases).

Comment: Georgy is correct; you first made `d` a type, then you made it a value. In Python, types are also values, but the dict type is not a dict value, it is a type value. This is a simple syntax mistake, you should use `:` for a type annotation, not `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using different variable name instead of `d` for `d = dict(zip(ln, lc))` or `d = Dict[str, int]`.

E.g.

```
from typing import Dict
d = Dict[str, int]

ln = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lc = [3, 5, 7]
x: d = dict(zip(ln, lc))
print(ln)
print(lc)
print(x)
```

Comment: Well, "the real code" uses `ch_top3` as a variable name but that doesn't change anything. The type error is just the same. (Which is expected, I would say.)

Comment: Just try using different variable names in these statements: `d = Dict[str, int]` and `d = dict(zip(ln, lc))`. e.g. `d = Dict[str, int]` and  `x = dict(zip(ln, lc))`

Comment: And then follow up with `d = x`? That's just the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: Why you need `d = x`? Please check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Along with the comments from @Georgy and @kaya3 I now see my typing error. Fixed this and `mypy` is now reporting `Success: no issues found`.