# VS Code's "Sort Imports" fails with exception

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever I invoke the "Sort Import" from the Visual Studio Code command palette, I get an exception stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/absingh/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.10.332292344/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py", line 30, in <module>
```

The stack trace of the exception is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/absingh/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.10.332292344/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py", line 30, in <module>

Error 2020-11-04 12:15:45:     runpy.run_path(module, run_name="__main__")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 252, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, path_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/absingh/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.10.332292344/pythonFiles/sortImports.py", line 12, in <module>
    import isort.main
  File "/Users/absingh/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.10.332292344/pythonFiles/lib/python/isort/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import settings
  File "/Users/absingh/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.10.332292344/pythonFiles/lib/python/isort/settings.py", line 31
    FILE_SKIP_COMMENTS: Tuple[str, ...] = (
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried switching the Language Server, but it does not help.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a python script with multiple import lines in VS Code:

   ```
   import sys
   import os
   from pprint import pprint
   ```
2. Open command palette by pressing [Command] + [Shift] + [p]
3. Search for "Sort Import"
4. Select and execute the command

Comment: We need the whole stacktrace and a [mre].

Comment: I've updated the full stack trace. Steps to reproduce:
1. Open a python script with multiple import lines
2. Open command palette
3. Search for "Sort Imports"
4. Select and execute the command.

Comment: Very good edit, I think this should be reopened. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions

Comment: You seem to be using the macOS system Python 2.7. Try with Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using Python 2.x

```
                                                            |
                                                            |
                                                           \!/
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 252, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, path_name)
```

while the module used to do "Sort Imports" only supports Python 3.6+. Let's start with this error from the `isort` module, which does the actual sorting of imports for the Python extension:

```
  File "/Users/absingh/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.10.332292344/pythonFiles/lib/python/isort/settings.py", line 31
    FILE_SKIP_COMMENTS: Tuple[str, ...] = (
```

That's a variable **type hint**, which was only introduced in **Python 3.6** (see [What are variable annotations in Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations-in-python-3-6))

**You need to [switch to a Python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) with at least Python 3.6**. (As a side note, unless you *really* need to, you shouldn't be using Python 2.7 anymore because it is no longer supported as of Jan 2020). You mentioned the new **Pylance** language server, but it does not matter whether you use **Pylance** or **Microsoft** as the language server. The problem is your Python version.

It is mentioned [in the VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_sort-imports) that `isort` is used:

> ### Sort Imports
>
> Sort Imports uses the isort package to consolidate specific imports
> from the same module into a single `import` statement and to organize
> `import` statements in alphabetical order.

It is mentioned [in the Python extension Changelog](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.python/changelog) that they upgraded to `isort 5.5.2` for the September 2020 release, along with dropped support for some older Python versions:

> #### Enhancements
>
> ...
> 8. Upgraded to isort 5.5.3. ([#14027](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14027))
>
> #### Code Health
>
> ...
> 3. Drop support for Python 3.5 (it reaches end-of-life on September 13, 2020 and isort 5 does not support it). ([#13459](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13459))
> 5. Disable sorting tests for Python 2.7 as isort5 is not compatible with Python 2.7. ([#13542](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13542))

Finally, the [isort 5.0.0 release notes](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/CHANGELOG/#500-penny-july-4-2020) mentions minimum Python version support:

> isort now requires Python 3.6+ to run but continues to support formatting on ALL versions of python including Python 2 code.

Comment: Thanks @Gino. I had been using iSort with py2 earlier and didn't know that the support for py2 was deprecated. I can confirm that iSort works on a py3 interpreter.