# What is the effect of dict access followed by colon operation in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

The following code does **not** cause an error, but it has no effect:

```
d = {"name": "Joey"}
d["age"]: 1
```

Notice that there's a typo, it should be `=` rather than `:`, how does python understand it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are variable annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations)

Comment: `d["age"] = 1` ;)