# What Does : Mean in Python? (NOT IN A LIST)

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I saw this code in the internet and I'm wounding what's `:` in this code?

```
dispatcher : Dispatcher = Updater.dispatcher
```

Comment: It's a type hint

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are variable annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's type-hinting.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

It helps the coder know what the object's intended type is. Also, some linter will shows error if you try to invoke some unsupported methods of a class object, similar to a static compiler.

Comment: But why when I wrote this command ```i : str = 123;print(type(i))``` I got ```<class 'int'>```, is it supposed to catch the error?

Comment: @Jawad it's type-**hinting**, not type-forcing. Python is still a duck-typed language, it just helps programmers not create avoidable bugs.