# Why is my pydantic model not displaying any values after setting it?

Tags: python, pydantic

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Test(BaseModel):
    val1 = str
    val2 = str

test = {
    "val1": "1010101",
    "val2": "1010101",
}
test_value= Test(**test)

print(test_value) # this doesn't display anything
print(test_value.val1) # this only display `<class 'str'>`
```

I have this simple structure of using pydantic. But when I try to print the value, it doesn't display anything.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `:` between the field name and its type instead of `=`.

```python
class Test(BaseModel):
    val1: str
    val2: str
```

Comment: Adding some explanation: `val1 = str` _assigns_ a value to the model's field, while `val1: str` _annotates_ the field that it should be a string. See related [What are variable annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39971929/2745495). Pydantic's model definitions takes advantage of _annotations_.