# django cors headers not working (yes ik a 100th people asked before but their solutions didn't work)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

my settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'channels',
    'chatterapi',
    'chatterchannels',
    "corsheaders",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS: True
```

*the chatter apps are my apps, and i'm also using django channels. tried moving cors headers up and down but had no luck.

idk how to get the actual headers but here is the log :

[image]

my views.py ?

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def createRoom(request):
    key = get_random_string(15)
    request.POST._mutable = True
    request.data['key'] = key
    request.POST._mutable = False
    print(request.data)
    serializer = RoomSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

I really don't know what's going on, let me know if there is any way I can help.
Is it possible that django channels overriding the runserver command is causing a conflict or something? (if that sounds dumb, please forgive me, cause I AM dumb)

Comment: **Typo:** `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS: True` is not an assignment it is a [type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations) you should be writing `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True` instead (Note `=` instead of `:`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the wrong syntax for setting a variable value. Change the line

```py
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS: True
```

to

```py
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the below code may not work

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

Try mentioning the hosts manually like below

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://localhost:8000",

]
```