# how to tell if a screen is add or change in django admin

Tags: python, django

I am trying to determine if the admin screen in Django is add or change in the save method. If I internet search on this, I cannot find any answer. What is the proper way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object has a primary key that is not `None` in case you update the model, so you can check this, for example with:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.pk is None:
            # add
            pass
        else:
            # change
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 1):

As with ModelForms, you can use a similar trick:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if obj._state.adding:
        # Adding
    else:
        # Editing

    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can check self.instance but just before super().**init**() is called.
Try out my solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845558/15080117

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30902279)